# zsh rotating yanking past 1 history

Tags: zsh

In normal bash after killing text with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd> / <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd> / <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>, you are able to yank it with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>y</kbd>.

In zsh this works.
However it's also possible to go back in the kill-ring/history with <kbd>meta/alt</kbd>+<kbd>y</kbd>.
In bash I'm able to press <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>y</kbd> as many times as I want and cycle though what has been deleted. However in zsh it moves a single kill back in the history and stops.

Can't seem to find any information on this and would like this feature to work as it does in normal Bash.

How is it possible to go back in the kill history with zsh more than one item?

Comment: This works for me, both with `zsh -f` and with my configuration. What version of zsh are you using? Does it work differently with `zsh -f`?

Comment: Very odd. When I run zsh -f zsh crashes to a more simple console without any other error output...

Comment: I have  5.7.1-1ubuntu2 according to aptitude.

Comment: `zsh -f` starts a new instance of zsh without your configuration files. Try how repeated Alt+Y works in that instance.

Comment: Ah yes, I was thrown off by the lack of any graphics at all...  yes it does seem to work there. Thanks, so I guess there's something messing with it in the confs. First place to look would be to disable each plugin... don't have many...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that problem lies somewhere in the zsh-sytax-highlighting plugin.

Looks like a known issue:
https://github.com/zsh-users/zsh-syntax-highlighting/issues/183